# VBA Time(Now) type mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue with the following code, it returns a type mismatch error message every time I open the file. The problem is that the file works fine on some PC's while, on my laptop, it triggers this error.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Sheets("Report").Unprotect
'
If Date <> Sheets("Report").Range("A1") Then

If Time(Now) >= 6 Then

Sheets("Report").Range("A1").Value = Date
Sheets("Report").Range("C3").Value = 0

End If
End If

Sheets("Report").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`Hour(Now())` should do it.   Hour Minute and Second, Day Month and Year.  Type Mismatch is trying to put differing types into incorrect variable types or trying to do comparison on two types that cant, so if you press F1, you can see time returns a time, and you're comparing to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Its interesting that this works on some PCs, as [Nathan_Sav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5414798/nathan-sav) shows replacing `Time(now)` with `Hour(now())` will get rid of the error, but I'm not sure it will be the fix you require.

```
If Hour(now()) >= 6 Then
    Sheets("Report").Range("A1").Value = Date
    Sheets("Report").Range("C3").Value = 0
End If
```

The above will run the code if the time is equal to or greater than 06:00 up to 23:59.

Is this what the goal was?

Again, as [Nathan_Sav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5414798/nathan-sav) has shown, other options could be: -

`Second(now()) >= 6` = Run if the minute is equal to or greater than 6 seconds up to the 59th second

`Minute(now()) >= 6` = Run if the hour is equal to or greater than 6 minutes up to the 59th minute

`Hour(now()) >= 6` = Run if the time is equal to or greater than 06:00 up to 23:59

`Day(now()) >= 6` = Run if the day is equal to or greater than 6 up to the top of the current month (i.e. 28 to 31)

`Month(now()) >= 6` = Run if the month is equal to or greater than June (the 6th month) up to December

Year does not fit in in this particular list.

Comment: The goal is that, on opening the file, if the computer's time (exact hour) at that particular moment exceeds 6AM, to reset some data (cell A1 and C3) while, if the time did not reach 6 AM(00:00 to 5:59 on the same day), not to reset the specific data.

Comment: However, the `Hour(now())` works fine, thank you very much both of you, Gary and Nathan, for the answer. I am still kind of confused how did the `Time(Now)` did the job on some other PC's... I did test it myself when I wrote the code, and it did work, indeed...